# how to choose components by "popularity"

Tags: distributors

An example.
I used Intellifet by Diodes Inc.
They are logic level mosfets, with  builtin protections.
There are many components, with slight different ratings.

Let's say many of these components fit my project.
I want to sort them not by their electrical ratings, but by their  "popularity"

> selling volumes
>
> availability in Europe from many vendors.

Are there any source of these informatioms ?

Note: I need to find a solution to speedup the choice made by "visiting the distributors web sites".
Small orders : each component, from 10 to 50 pieces.

Comment: What's popularity got to do with it? Choose the component with the specs you need, at the price you can pay, and you can obtain. Usually means you're tied to two or three distributors if you're a hobbyist.

Comment: I knew old and wise engineers that prefer, for example, to source power supply regulators with variable output, even if a fixed output fits the current project. Sometimes we need a wide look, we prefer components not too specific and easier to obtain.

Comment: Some distributors will let you sort by quantity in stock, which is probably at least somewhat correlated with "popularity".

Comment: @Massimo - so what you really are looking for is long term availability? The more application specific your component is, the less likely it will be available in future. 7805 regulators will be available until the end of time, but maybe not LT189995341 super low noise treble fuzz regulators.

Comment: @awjlogan - by choosing a 'popular' component there's probably a greater likelihood that you'll have chosen one which the manufacturer will keep in production for alonger period of time and/or there'll be comparable equivalents from other manufacturers you could switch to if necessary.

Comment: @Massimo Components are choose acconding a design, prefirable for those that can be used in other designs. For popularity is according the design to meet the circuits or toys that are trend, for example drones or arduinos. But if you see the parts which these are made you can see a lot of components that have more than 20 years on the market, so are easily to get from a dealer.

Comment: The automotive industry demands that IC manufacturers commit to long product availability, for an IC to be automotive-rated. (There are other requirements like wide temperature range, so price may be a bit higher for automotive grade parts.)

Answer (score 5):

Go to a distributor, pick components that are "active" and sort by stock level. Compare several. Look for **second sources** where appropriate and compare, including details. A part may be very popular, but not in a certain package or temperature range.

Double check the manufacturer's website to be sure that the part is recommended for new designs.

Carefully consider who else is likely to be using the parts. If they're aimed specifically or mostly at something with a design life of 6 months (eg. cell phones or whatever the next big thing is) and your product has to be available for 15 or 20 years, there is a good possibility it will be obsoleted before you even get many out there.

There is still an element of chance here, it's possible that there  is a shortage today of the part you should be specifying and it will be the best one in 3 months when your product ships. There's no one way of dealing with that sort of thing except keeping an eye on the market. Right now some passives are in short supply.

As far as actual sales volumes, those numbers are not freely provided by anyone, as far as I know. Occasionally teasers will be quoted from very expensive reports (such as market share of microcontrollers) and you can read the trade press for that sort of thing, but it's not terribly reliable and often not current or has some kind of baked-in bias by the folks who paid for it.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I am looking for a simpler way, to avoid the tedious and time wasting manual wandering from one web site to another.

Comment: @Massimo  Sure. The only simpler way that I know of would be to hire someone who has that knowledge and experience or is willing to put in the work. If design was easy, anyone would be able to do it well.

Answer (score 1):

While its a good idea to use parts that everyone else is using, this can also be a drawback. For example: This year Murata [discontinued](https://www.ttiinc.com/content/ttiinc/en/resources/marketeye/categories/passives/me-zogbi-20180302.html) their low end line of capacitors the GRM series. The MLCC capacitor market was already near a shortage, they discontinued their line and everyone had to switch. The line was popular because it was cheap, and the voltages were high. If everyone buys at the same time then you'll be left out and you won't be able to build your design.

You probably want to talk to a supply chain management company for electronic parts. [Silicon Expert](https://www.siliconexpert.com/node/60) is one, but they are expensive and will only save you money if you are buying millions of dollars of parts. They will be able to tell you which are the most popular parts, and they'd better be able to do that, because they are expensive (but worth it if your a big company)

The other one that is more affordable is [ciiva](https://ciiva.com/), they should be able to give you the information you desire.

But more than that, they will be able to give you cross references on parts and keep track of End Of Life (EOL).

Comment: an example of a good tool: Octopart is the easiest search engine for electronic parts. Search across hundreds of distributors 
and thousands of manufacturers.

https://octopart.com